# How to display text in Textarea of wmd-editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, wmd

I want to display text in the `Textarea` of wmd-editor . The text I will display in the `Textarea` has already been written by wmd-editor (like a Reverse operation) from HTML to Textarea of wmd-editor, but when I try to do this using

```
<div id="wmd-preview" >{!! $question->qst_body !!}</div>
```

then I get this result :

[image]

but I want to get this result :

[image]

**any ideas ? *thanks***

Comment: what is shown in `<textarea id="wmd-input" class="wmd-panel"></textarea>` ? Isn't that what you search? see here: https://github.com/derobins/wmd/blob/master/readme_OLD.txt

Comment: No, this Textarea converts text to html, but I want to get a way to reverse the conversion from HTML to text

Comment: what for is the button `<>`? code or source view?

Comment: Why not you are using `textarea` instead of `div`